# (function($) { ..})(jQuery); function defined in this wrapper/closure can not be called outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following block ,where I have defined 1 function, I am trying to call that function outside block, it gives me function undefined error.why?

```
    (function($) {
       function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
          return num1 + num2;
       }

    })(jQuery);

addNumbers(2,3) return error undefined function.
```

what can i do to make  addNumbers() to call outside of this block?

Comment: Why is the `addNumbers()` function outside?

Comment: You can simply return the `inner` function to a variable and use it anywhere outside. See answer for more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a basic scoping issue. If you declare a function inside another function, it is only accessible inside that function. You can't access it outside.

Comment: This does not answer the `what can i do to make addNumbers() to call outside of this block?` part. The inner function is accessible if you return it. That is how closures work

Comment: @SandeepNayak My apologies, I didn't see that part of the question. Yes, returning the function works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return the `inner` function to a variable and use it anywhere outside.

```js
 var myFunction = (function($) {
       function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
          return num1 + num2;
       }
       return addNumbers;

  })(jQuery);

alert(myFunction(2,3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions defined in other functions are scoped to that function. They can only be called by other code from within that scope. Therefore in order to call the `addNumbers()` function, the call would have to be inside the parent function of the `addNumbers()` function.

**Example:**

```js
function test() {
  function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
    console.log(num1 + num2);
  }
  addNumbers(2, 3);
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that you define a function in one scope (anonymous function), and try to run it from another (global). You have to do it vise-versa:

```
// Declare function first.
function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
   return num1 + num2;
}

// Now, inside anonymous function - you can use your function (because it in global scope, and accessible from here).
(function($) {
   console.log(addNumbers(2,3));
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

immediate funtions is anonymous. so, If you want to access inner function from outside, you have to make return for value or function.

```
var test = (function($) {
  return function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  }
}(jQuery));

console.log(test(2,3));
```

Comment: while this may provide an answer to the question, it is helpful to include some form of commentary indicating what it is exactly that will solve the problem.

Comment: thank for your comment. I added some commentary about this code.